# The name 'SessionState' does not exist in the current context

Tags: session-state

I installed new sitecore 9.3 project, i see error when build project, filename :"\sitecore\admin\sessionsummary.aspx"

[image]

Comment: I believe this is not an issue, just close this file and run your solution build.
The same way if you open any existing cshtml or aspx extension file then there may be a chance to get error/warning but if you close that file and build your solution issue will gone.

Comment: If issue still persist then please share logs

Answer (score 2):

**SitecoreSessionState** class is part of the assembly **Sitecore.ExM.Framework.dll** in the namespace **Sitecore.ExM.Framework.Distributed.Sessions**

```
namespace Sitecore.ExM.Framework.Distributed.Sessions
{
  public enum SitecoreSessionState
  {
    Abandoned,
    Ended,
    Active,
  }
}
```

Probably you didn't add reference to the assembly in your project. Did you build your project in the wwwroot folder?

Comment: Already dll in project bin and I gave reference but still same issue.

Comment: I guess you are using  SessionSummary from old version of Sitecore and the code was changed.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the reference to Sitecore.ExM.Framework.dll in your code instead of SessionState.Active you should be using SitecoreSessionState.Active, like this:

```
        private static Owner ToOwner(OwnerInfo ownerInfo)
        {
            string status;
            switch (ownerInfo.RecentSession.SessionState)
            {
                case SitecoreSessionState.Active:
                    {
                        status = "Online";
                        break;
                    }
                case SitecoreSessionState.Ended:
                    {
                        status = "Shut Down";
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    status = "Crashed";
                    break;
            }
        }
```